# .toggleClass en solo 1 elemento aunque existan varios con la misma clase

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear un menú multinivel pero no sé cómo hacer que solo se añada la clase al elemento que está dentro del `<li>` que he pulsado.

La idea final es pulsar la flecha que he creado con JS y que añada o quite una clase en el `ul.sub-menu`, pero solo en el `ul.submenu` que está al mismo nivel que el span de la flecha (este se crea como hijo del `li` que tiene la clase `.menu-item-has-children`

Este es el código:

HTML

```
<nav class="menu-principal">
      <ul>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children">
          <a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">El equipo</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Nuestras instalaciones</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">El equipo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nuestras instalaciones</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cómo trabajamos</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Cómo trabajamos</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Vídeos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Pide presupuesto</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">El equipo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nuestras instalaciones</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cómo trabajamos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>  
  </nav>
```

**JS**

```
// CREAR ELEMENTO PARA ABRIR MENU EN MOVIL (FLECHA)
  $(".menu-item-has-children > a").append('<span class="btn-mostrar"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>');

 // ABRIR SUBMENU AL HACER CLICK EN FLECHA
    $(".btn-mostrar").click(function(){
        $(".sub-menu").toggleClass("mostrar");
    });

});
```

Comment: ¿Puedes cambiar el HTML?

Comment: Podrías subir el CSS también? para poder ayudarte y hacer pruebas reales

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usando jQuery's `.next()` asi:

```
$(".btn-mostrar").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next(".sub-menu").toggleClass("mostrar");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

En programación, existe el concepto del `this` que en el caso de eventos (que es lo que nos ocupa) se refiere al elemento que lo ha disparado. De tal manera que el `this` en el caso de un evento del tipo **click**, hace referencia al elemento al que se pulsó con el ratón.

Basándonos en este principio, podemos hacer que tan solo se muestre el `.sub-menu` hermano del elemento al que hacemos **click**, que en tu caso es el `.btn-mostrar`:

```
$(".btn-mostrar").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').toggleClass("mostrar");
});
```

Con eso, ya te debería de aplicar la clase **mostrar** tan solo al submenú que corresponda.